# Uncaught Type Error for a function that already exists

Tags: javascript, json, blob, project

At first run, the toBlob function wasn't defined in our project's package.json thus making it undefined, although the desired result was achieved. Now that our package.json is updated and toBlob is now recognized, the console still returns the same error, as stated in the title of this question.

I have no idea what to debug. toBlob is a function available to canvas.

Comment: please share the code as well.

Comment: Share the code on JSFiddle, or within your question.

Comment: A `TypeError` is not a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: Give more info about the issue you are facing or share the code snippet